# Echo a PDF file to the user from binary string

Tags: php, pdf

I'm getting a binary (PDF file) from a webservice and I need to show it to the user on the page. I have managed to download it using headers but I need to print it to the page **inside a div** not download it. This what I have at the moment:

```
$binaryString = '.....';
$convertedFIle= base64_decode($base64);
file_put_contents('my.pdf', $convertedFIle);

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my.pdf"');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tought about what @CountKyle said and i manage to get it working.
Since i was getting the PDF from a SOAP call and from an AJAX i did it a bit different.

```
var htmlText = '<embed style="position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;"'
                        + ' type="application/pdf"'
                        + ' src="data:application/pdf;base64,'
                        + escape(server_response)
                        + '"></embed>';

$( "#modal-preview-pdf-container" ).html(htmlText);
```

Now it is in the correct div that i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The headers you have set will tell the browser to download the file instead of displaying it, if you want to display it, you will need to embed it in an iframe or an object.

Assuming that your pdf is in the document root, you could do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="/myPdf.pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```